# How to run maven commands automatically, not from command?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom

I am working on a project that I need to build a maven pipeline for versioning and release.
I am doing like this:

1. Change version manually by running `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.0.0`.
2. Check the project detail and detect if it is snapshot or release. I have my own custom plugin and a parameter which returns the final version, e.g. `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. **BUT HOW CAN I** return this value and feed it to another plugin?
3. I compile the project and generate the jar with new name, from 2.
4. And...

I know I can handle every step by a CL command but what I want to know and confused me is that how to embed everything in `pom.xml` and just run `mvn install` and nothing else.

Each plugin needs some arguments that should be able to change that. I know I can use the `<argument>` tag under `<configuration>`, but some of the plugins do not have the argument tag.

How can I have a solid solution and config everything in my parent POM beforehand? 
Also I do have my own plugin but I am not sure if it is possible to embed all things to that and I just run `myplugin:Install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building a SNAPSHOT, you usually just run `mvn clean verify` on your project. If you need special plugins, you can configure them in the `configuration` section following the advice in the plugin description.

For building a release version, you should use a build server (like Jenkins). There, you can construct all the steps much easier than in Maven. If for some reason, you cannot do that, use the maven release plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a running setup in Gradle with Archivia and ... , I am just creating a Maven build solution to replace the gradle task.
so that clearly I can not change any technology or tool.

Comment: Also as you can see in my question, I know how to use each profile individually but a bit confused about putting all together, and yes I know I can use verify but I have special condition and I am happy with my own plugin and as you can read in OP just wanna know how to setup the whole picture

Comment: Sorry, but I need to stress that Maven expects that you follow Maven best practises, otherwise you very quickly run into huge problems. So my first aim is to make sure that you are really _really_ really sure you want to go the hard and painful way instead of the Maven way.

Comment: That said, you can configure your own plugin inside the POM (like any other plugin) and you can set all plugin parameters through the `<configuration>` section. You can also set Maven properties in your Maven plugin and use these properties to configure other plugins.

Comment: Note again, that unless this is just a toy project, you will _need_ a build server like Jenkins, Bamboo, Circle CI, Travis CI eventually.

Comment: Let me add, though, that you do not need a plugin to determine the version of the project because this is just `${project.version}`.